# finding array index based on value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to find the index based on the value stored within it.

This would normally be easy, but the array I'm working with is highly nested. Each index `0,1,2` has fields `f1,f2,f3` . I'm trying to find which index `0,1,2` has in its `f2` field the value `this` stored in it. In this case, it's index `0`. So that's the output I'm looking for. Is there a neat trick in PHP to do this effectively?

```
$somearray[0][f1] = "not this";
$somearray[0][f2] = "this"; 
$somearray[0][f3] = "not this"; 

$somearray[1][f1] = "not this";
$somearray[1][f2] = "not this";
$somearray[1][f3] = "not this"; 

$somearray[2][f1] = "not this"; 
$somearray[2][f2] = "not this"; 
$somearray[2][f3] = "not this";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this case, it's index 0. So that's
>   the output I'm looking for.

```
$somearray[0]['f1'] = "not this";
$somearray[0]['f2'] = "this";
$somearray[0]['f3'] = "not this";

$somearray[1]['f1'] = "not this";
$somearray[1]['f2'] = "not this";
$somearray[1]['f3'] = "not this";

$somearray[2]['f1'] = "not this";
$somearray[2]['f2'] = "not this";
$somearray[2]['f3'] = "not this";

foreach($somearray as $key => $value)
{
  if($value['f2'] === 'this')
  {
     echo $key; // find out the key
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
```

Comment: Thank you. Does what I was trying to do.